# 11.10 : no window manager, no applications, just tty

Tags: 11.10, window-manager

logged into my ubuntu account and found myself on a screen with just my desktop background and nothing else.

pressing the volume buttons displays the indicator, and i can get to a tty session but i can't do anything else. restarting gdm doesn't seem to help at all either

I'm running 11.10, upgraded from a wubi install of 11.04.

any thoughts?

Comment: try running lightdm from the tty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greg, not knowing which default DM you are using, it could be several things at fault. Unfortunately lacking enough information to answer with confidence, but would suspect that the desktop-manager session has become a mess somehow.

Knowing what was occurring prior to the problem would be helpful. Was this just post-upgrade or had there been recently installed packages, or was there something else occurring prior to login?.

Depending on which DM you are using by default (gnome-shell or unity) you might want to drop down into a recovery console and try to reset the DM, if you believe that is the root of the problem.

Know that the command: `unity --reset` should restore the unity DM defaults, but have not had any luck while the X server is running and trying that command from a tty.

Seems it does not quite finish. Know there is a command to replace the gnome-shell as well, and if you should also load the gnome-session-fallback just in case. HTH, not sure if this answers, but trying to.

Comment: `unity --reset` mostly worked. Going to reset and see if it's fully fixed. It did throw a bunch of this though: `"compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x4e00099!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.`

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you have problems with the launcher, unity --reset-icons is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your desktop background, if a menu pops up, **create a new folder**.

Double click on the folder and a nautilus window should pop up. Browse to location **/usr/share/applications** and find program **Compiz**, double click on it and magic might happen.

If nothing really happens, go into **CompizConfig Settings Manager** and check if the **Unity Plugin** is enabled. If you don't have this program, open a **Terminal**, and run command: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` or if you dont even have Compiz, run command: `sudo apt-get install compiz`

---

If no menu pops up, go to a **tty session**, **login** and run commands:

```
sudo killall lightdm
startx
```

---

If that doesn't seem to work either, check if **unity** and **compiz** are installed. Run commands from a tty session:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz unity
```

---

Hope that helps :P

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem - no window manager, no decoration, no apps started, and only an Xterm! It turned out, that I had somehow, (clumsiness comes to mind) selected "Recovery Session" under the Gear symbol on the Login screen. I changed it to "Ubuntu", and when I logged in, everything was back. Log out, and click on the Gear!

Comment: i wasn't in recovery mode. It was a regular session with no window manager.